# QuickBlox Video Chat Quality

Tags: ios, quickblox

We have this iOS project that uses QuickBlox Video Chat. Basing from the sample app they've given, we were able to implement it successfully. When we tested it, the quality looks a bit bad. Does anyone know how to up the quality of the video chat?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change the video quality by setting kQBVideoChatFrameQualityPreset in videoChatConfiguration,

```
    NSMutableDictionary *videoChatConfiguration = [[QBSettings videoChatConfiguration] mutableCopy];
    [videoChatConfiguration setObject:@20 forKey:kQBVideoChatCallTimeout];
    [videoChatConfiguration setObject:@10 forKey:kQBVideoChatVideoFramesPerSecond];
    // config video quality here
    [videoChatConfiguration setObject:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium forKey:kQBVideoChatFrameQualityPreset];
    [QBSettings setVideoChatConfiguration:videoChatConfiguration];
```

The available options:

```
//achieve high quality video and audio output.defaultvalue.
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 4_0);
//achieve output video and audio bitrates suitable for sharing over WiFi.
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 4_0);
//achieve output video and audio bitrates suitable for sharing over 3G.
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetLow NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 4_0);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works.  We are currently using Medium preset. Although, it seems the framerate is bad whenever we try it on a iOS device in iOS7 (tested on iPad2 and iPhone5) but it works fine on iOS6. What do you think could be the reason for this?

Comment: @user1041274 I'm not sure what makes the difference of framerate. How about set higher kQBVideoChatVideoFramesPerSecond in iOS7 device?