# How to improve video quality of my quickblox chat app?

Tags: ios, quickblox, vp8, vp9

I've developing enterprise iOS app. On my app, I m integrating Quickblox for video call.

As I know, quickblox ios sdk supports VP8, H264 for video codec.

It's video quality is good but not great when make video call between android-ios (iOS-android).

So I m going to add VP9 for my video call app.

Is there any solution or example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From QuickBlox documentation:

**Video codecs: VP8 vs VP9 vs H264**

H264 is the most preferred video codec for iOS.

Chrome added support for H264 video codec in 50 revision.

VP9 for iOS exists only in development and webrtc doesn't have a stable version, so we are waiting for a stable one.

VP8 should be used if you do support iOS7 because iOS7 does not have H264 hardware support.

H264 is the only one video codec for iOS that has hardware support.

**Video quality**

1. Video quality depends on hardware you use. iPhone 4s will not handle FullHD rendering. But iPhone 6+ will.
2. Video quality depends on network you use and how many connections you have.

For multi-calls set lower video quality. For peer-to-peer calls you can set higher quality.

WebRTC has auto scaling of video resolution and quality to keep network connection active.

To get best quality and performance you should use H264.

1. If you do support iOS 7, then WebRTC automatically switches to VP8 even if you set H264.
2. If some android devices do not support H264, then automatically VP8 will be used.
3. If both caller and callee have H264 support, then H264 will be used.

http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-ios#Video_codecs:_VP8_vs_VP9_vs_H264

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Reference from [Video Chat quality quickbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111654/quickblox-video-chat-quality)

you need to set **kQBVideoChatFrameQualityPreset** in **videoChatConfiguration**,

> ```
> NSMutableDictionary *videoChatConfiguration = [[QBSettings videoChatConfiguration] mutableCopy];
>     [videoChatConfiguration setObject:@20 forKey:kQBVideoChatCallTimeout];
>     [videoChatConfiguration setObject:@10 forKey:kQBVideoChatVideoFramesPerSecond];
>     // config video quality here
>     [videoChatConfiguration setObject:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium forKey:kQBVideoChatFrameQualityPreset];
>     [QBSettings setVideoChatConfiguration:videoChatConfiguration];
> ```

Available option is

> ```
> //achieve high quality video and audio output.defaultvalue.
> AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 4_0);
> //achieve output video and audio bitrates suitable for sharing over WiFi.
> AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 4_0);
> //achieve output video and audio bitrates suitable for sharing over 3G.
> AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetLow NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 4_0);
> ```

Comment: Hi @Badal Shah.
Thanks for your answer.
This does not works on current version QB SDK (2.5).